# Grouping NSArray By Looping?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting

I am trying to isolate elements in an array.  I have an NSArray containing over 100000 NSNumber Objects.  The problem I have is they are arranged by increments of 3.

```
processarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (loopstart = 0; loopstart < arraycount; loopstart ++)

{
    arrayvalue = [[mesharray objectAtIndex: loopstart] floatValue];
    coordinate = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: arrayvalue];
    [processarray addObject: coordinate];
    [printgcodetoconsole appendFormat: @"\nCOORDINATE: %@", coordinate];

}
```

For Example, my array looks like this:

- COORDINATE: 5567
- COORDINATE: 1065
- COORDINATE: 1564
- COORDINATE: 3432
- COORDINATE: 6123
- COORDINATE: 9345
- COORDINATE: 1856
- COORDINATE: 2765
- COORDINATE: 1998
- COORDINATE: 9087
- COORDINATE: 2234
- COORDINATE: 5467

What I need is a way to group the correct values together in terms of X, Y, and Z because they are points in space like:

- NEW ARRAY OBJECT: (X5567, Y1065, Z1564)

and so on…

There are no similarities between the objects in the array except that they are all NSNumber objects.

Thanks In Advance!

I am currently printing this array as strings in a NSTextView and I can't figure out how to isolate the strings without messing up the loop with this code:

```
[printgcodetoconsole appendFormat: @"\nCOORDINATE: %@", coordinate];
```

I would really prefer something more like:

```
NSNumber * X;
NSNumber * Y;
NSNumber * Z;

[printgcodetoconsole appendFormat: @"\n X%@, Y%@, Z%@", X, Y, Z];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check when the counter `loopstart` is multiple of 3 and group the last 3 values on a sub-array:

```
NSMutableArray *subArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (loopstart = 0; loopstart < arraycount; loopstart ++) {
    arrayvalue = [[mesharray objectAtIndex:loopstart] floatValue];
    coordinate = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: arrayvalue];
    [subArray addObject:coordinate];
    if (loopstart % 3 == 0) {
        [processarray addObject:subArray];
        subArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jero!  Thanks for your help.  Is there a way I can add to that by separating the X, Y, and Z values?  I am printing these as strings to a NSTextView like above...

Comment: `for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [mesharray count]; i += 3)
{
    NSString *coordinate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(X%f, Y%f, Z%f)", [[mesharray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue], [[mesharray objectAtIndex:(i + 1)] floatValue], [[mesharray objectAtIndex:(i + 2)] floatValue]];
    [processarray addObject:coordinate];
}`

Comment: JeroValli's comment will display them as it goes.  If you want to use his original post, and if the coordinates are in the proper pattern in the original array (i.e. x,y,z,x,y,z) then each subArray should naturally be in the same pattern: subArray[0] being X, subArray[1] being Y, etc.  You can just say `[printgcodetoconsole appendFormat: @"\n X%@, Y%@, Z%@", subArray[0], subArray[1], subArray[2]];`

Comment: Hi Guys… I may have failed to mention that one of the arrays is a NSMutableArray and i'm wondering if that could be the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys… the answer turned out to be a variation on JeroValli's idea about using a modulo.  It's a damn sexy idea I might add.  Thanks Jero and everyone else involved.

Answer (score 0):

This simple code will take every three items from meshArray, put them into a new array and insert that into a larger array (so that you have an array of arrays).

```
NSArray *meshArray = /* obtain from somewhere */;
NSAssert(([meshArray count] % 3) == 0, @"Array does not contain multiple of 3");

NSMutableArray coordinates = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [meshArray count]; i += 3)
    [coordinates addObject:[meshArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 3)]];
```

Alternatively, if you want, you can key them using a dictionary:

```
NSArray *meshArray = /* obtain from somewhere */;
NSAssert(([meshArray count] % 3) == 0, @"Array does not contain multiple of 3");

NSMutableArray coordinates = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [meshArray count]; i += 3)
{
    NSDictionary *coordinate = @{ @"X" : meshArray[i], @"Y" : meshArray[i + 1], @"Z" : meshArray[i + 2] };
    [coordinates addObject:coordinate];
}
```

Comment: I keep getting the same error the the array count is out of bounds…

Comment: That's unusual... the NSAssert makes sure there are the right number of elements in the array, and the loop does not exceed the bounds. Are you sure the number of elements in the array is a multiple of 3, and that you are using a debug build? You aren't accessing this array from multiple threads?

Comment: That's the problem then.  There may be extra elements like garbage 0 values.  It's a parsed XML file, so that could be why it's not working.

Comment: Sorry guys… maybe this NSArray sorting thing is the wrong idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys… the answer turned out to be a variation on JeroValli's idea about using a modulo.  It's a damn sexy idea I might add.  Thanks Jero and everyone else involved.

```
for (loopstart = 0; loopstart < arraycount; loopstart ++)

        {
            arrayvalue = [[mesharray objectAtIndex: loopstart] floatValue];
            point = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: arrayvalue];
            [coordinates addObject: point];
            if (loopstart % 3 == 0)
            {
                [printgcodetoconsole appendFormat: @"\nCOORDINATE: X%@", point];
            }
            else if (loopstart % 3 == 1)
            {
                [printgcodetoconsole appendFormat: @"\nCOORDINATE: Y%@", point];
            }
            else if (loopstart % 3 == 2)
            {
                [printgcodetoconsole appendFormat: @"\nCOORDINATE: Z%@", point];
            }
```